# Dense Rank with paging and order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, window-functions

I am using custom paging in my application so each time i fetch latest 10 records from my Database and displayed on my app.

My problem is

I want to fetch latest user information on top.

While fetching information each user have more than one rows so i use dense_rank function for grouping those records.

for example

```
RRowNo   UserID  Location  CreatedOn

1       Avsih     Delhi       06-02-2014
1       Avsih     Mumbai      06-02-2014
1       Avsih     Kerala      06-02-2014
2       Nimmi     UP          06-02-2014
3       Rahul1    Delhi       06-02-2014
4       Rahul2    Mumbai      06-02-2014
5       Rahul3    Kerala      06-02-2014
6       Rahul4    UP          06-02-2014
7       Rahul5    Delhi       06-02-2014
8       Rahul6    Mumbai      06-02-2014
9       Rahul7    Kerala      06-02-2014
10      Rahul8    UP          06-02-2014
11      Rahul9    UP          07-02-2014
```

Consider my table name is emp

My query is

```
select * 
from (
   select dense_rank() over (order by userid asc) as rowno,
   from emp
) as tab 
where rowno>='1' and rowno<='10'
order by Createdon desc
```

Rahul9 is my latest record (ie createdon must be 07/02/2014) 
i want that record to be top most.But by using that query i cant fetch
so please help how to modify this query.

Comment: Please don't compare apples (numbers) with oranges (strings). `'1'` is a character value. `1` is a number. And please add the tag for the DBMS you are using (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want the users with the most recent `createdon` first.  Assuming `createon` is the   same for all users, try:

```
select * 
from (select dense_rank() over (order by createdon desc, userid asc) as rowno
      from emp
     ) tab 
where rowno >= 1 and rowno <= 10
order by Createdon desc;
```

Comment: Yes i want most recently created records first
Your query is working fine
Thanks Gordon,
actually first time i use ranking function so i don't have mush idea in it.

Comment: @user3278909 . . . They are very powerful and fun (for people like me) to learn about.

Answer (score 0):

A sub query such as

```
select * from ( select dense_rank() over (order by userid asc) as rowno, * from emp
inner join (select userid,MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxCreatedOn FROM emp GROUP BY userid) a ON a.userid = emp.userid
) as tab where rowno>='1' and rowno<='10' order by a.MaxCreatedon desc
```

Where you are getting the most recent date per user and then joining to that might do the trick?

Comment: I execute above query both query are same.

the record rahul9 is still on 11th position ie its rowno must be 11



select * from ( select dense_rank() over (order by SAmple.userid asc) as rowno,a.* from SAmple
inner join (select userid,MAX(CreatedOn) AS MaxCreatedOn FROM SAmple GROUP BY userid) a ON a.userid = SAmple.userid
) as tab 
--where rowno>='1' and rowno<='10' 
order by tab.MaxCreatedon desc

Comment: I hadn't spotted that createdon was same for all users, sorry.